# Zurb Foundation topbar dropdown disappears on small screens

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, navigationbar

This is troubling because the only reason I want a topbar is for smaller screens. The dropdown works fine in medium and large, but disappears on smaller screens. I've read it needs to be inside a 12-width column, but that doesn't seem to help. It actually introducted another (minor) problem where the bar no longer fills the screen's width. The dropdown is only 4 characters, how could it be too large? What am I missing here?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="fixed small-12 medium-12 large-12 column">
<nav class="top-bar" style="color: white;" data-options="is_hover:false" data-topbar="">
    <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name"></li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
        <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

large:
[image: large]

small:
[image: small]

Comment: did you inspect element? usually foundation inserts there a burger menu

Comment: There is no burger menu, but that would be nice. What am I looking for? The dropdown looks like it is below the topbar, yet not visible or clickable.

Comment: well something has to be there. it most probably makes it display none on tablet-down screens. if you don't want margins, use row collapse classes

Comment: Can you provide an online example or a link to a fiddle with your work. It would be easier to help/inspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still needs some tweaking, but I fixed it. I added

```
style="display: none;"
```

to

```
<ul class="title-area">
```

It looks like they were both trying to occupy the same space.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read it needs to be inside a 12-width column...

I really don't think that this is right; that is the reason for the problem you introduced.

Actually I would change

```
<div class="fixed small-12 medium-12 large-12 column">
```

to

```
<div class="fixed">
```

If want it to show for small screens only then you could do like this

```
<div class="fixed show-for-small-only">
```

Also don't forget to reinitialize or reapply listeners as per [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) (at the very bottom of the page).

```
$(document).foundation();
```

and

```
$(document).foundation('topbar', 'reflow');
```

Also note the list items should contain links. Change

```
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
```

to

```
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
```

---

It's not exactly the same, but maybe helpful. I use top-bar for medium  and larger screens, and I use tab-bar for small screens.

You can find inspiration on my [website](https://come-malaka-expenses.herokuapp.com). **Feel free to inspect it**. It's also on [GitHub](https://github.com/Elyasin/Come-Malaka-Expenses).

It is based on the [Zurb-Foundation 5 documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html). Shouldn't be too difficult to cope with I hope.

Comment: Thanks Elyasin, but I solved this above, I'm just unable to mark it as accepted as of yet. 

I actually ended up making all of the changes you mentioned (except links, because this is just a proof of concept). Having it inside or outside a 12-width column has no effect. The real fix was setting the ul #title-area to display: none;

Comment: Then you have to accept the other answer, since that solved your issue. If it was useful to you please upvote mine.

Comment: I upvoted yours. It was helpful, but it wasn't the answer, just stuff that I needed to do anyway.

Comment: I know, I got it. You should accept your own answer though. To let the people know it is solved. (You'll get a badge for that too.) It is encouraged to do so actually.

Comment: I need to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also noticed you are missing the mobile menu icon.

Should be an li in the title-area

```
     <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take    out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
```